# Converting 'x' value of a CGPoint ivar to NSTimeInterval?

Tags: objective-c, casting, cgpoint

I have a velocity ivar defined as a CGPoint.

I need to somehow extract just the 'x' value of velocity, and then use this to call-send a message to the following method signature

```
-(void) adjustTimer:(NSTimeInterval*)newInterval
```

How do I obtain just the 'x' value of a CGPoint?
Do I then need to convert or cast this result before calling my adjustTimer method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
NSTimeInterval t = (NSTimeInterval) point.x;
[self adjustTimer:&t];
point.x = t;
```

Note that `NSTimeInterval` is a double and x is a CGFloat, so it's not safe to pass a direct pointer to your x value.

Comment: Thanks!
just confused about that last line 'point.x = t;'
Why are you redefining point.x?

I'm probably missing something very basic here...

Comment: I assumed you wanted to change the value of point.x in-place.